# NA Signal Handling in Java: System.exit not working when accessing external objects inside lambda

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, jna

I'm trying to implement a way to perform a graceful shutdown of my Java application when it receives a SIGINT signal (e.g., when the user presses `CTRL+C`). I want to persist scheduled jobs to disk and perform other cleanup tasks before the application shuts down. I'm using JNA to hook into the C library's `signal` function.

Here's my code:

```java
import com.sun.jna.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SignalHandlerExample {

    public interface CLibrary extends Library {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.load("c", CLibrary.class);
        void signal(int signal, SignalHandler handler);
    }

    public interface SignalHandler extends com.sun.jna.Callback {
        void handle(int signal);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AtomicBoolean shutdownRequested = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        CLibrary.INSTANCE.signal(2, signal -> {
            // Handle SIGINT here
            System.out.println("SIGINT received");
            shutdownRequested.set(true);
            System.exit(130); // When AtomicBoolean is removed, System.exit proceeds
        });

        // Main loop
        while (true) {
            if (shutdownRequested.get()) {
                System.out.println("Shutdown requested");
                // ... Try to persist jobs to disk ...
                System.exit(130);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);  // Sleep for 1 second.
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program doesn't exit when I call `System.exit(130)` inside the signal handler if I access an object from outside the lambda (in this case, an `AtomicBoolean`). Instead, I see this message in my IDE console: `Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51306', transport: 'socket'`, but the process continues running and the scheduled jobs are still executing.

However, if I remove the access to the `AtomicBoolean` and simplify the signal handler like this:

```java
CLibrary.INSTANCE.signal(2, signal -> {
    // Handle SIGINT here
    System.out.println("SIGINT received");
    System.exit(130); // Works when no outside object is accessed.
});
```

The program shuts down as expected when `System.exit(130)` is called.

I am puzzled by this behavior. Why does accessing an object outside of the lambda cause `System.exit` to not work as expected? Are there limitations or specific behaviors of JNA and signal handling that I should be aware of?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What’s the point in this `// ... Try to persist jobs to disk ...` part when the signal handler does already call `System.exit(130);` *immediately* after setting the `AtomicBoolean` (while the main thread may still wait up to a second)?

Comment: You're not supposed to install a signal handler, since it interferes with the JVM's signal handler. Use a shutdown hook. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)

Comment: @Holger the first `System.exit(130)` is for illustration only, to showcase that the program won't exit if atomic boolean is set, but when the line is removed the program can exit

Comment: @boneill can't use shutdown hooks because IO streams area is already closed before the hook triggers making any database IO operation fail.

Comment: @quarks perhaps don't close the IO streams area first? If you want to use signals, a google search is all that's needed: "java signal handling"

Comment: But as far as I can understand, you don’t want to have an `exit`  call in the signal handler at all, as the purpose of the `AtomicBoolean` is to let the main thread perform an action. So why do you care whether that exit call works? Shouldn’t you focus on the question whether the main thread perceives the change of the `AtomicBoolean`?